# Set constraints on present() in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, mapbox

I am currently using [MapBox SDK](https://www.mapbox.com/help/ios-navigation-sdk/#install-the-navigation-sdk-for-ios) to generate a navigation controller within my app.

I have managed to get everything looking exactly the way I want except for spacing at the bottom or the screen

I currently present the navigation using:-

```
func presentAndRemoveMapview(_ navigationViewController: NavigationViewController) {
    present(navigationViewController, animated: true) {
        self.mapView?.removeFromSuperview()
        self.mapView = nil
    }
}
```

But when I try to set any constraints to the navigationViewController xcode returns errors informing me I am unable to set any constraints against the controller.

I have also attempted to create my own views using the MGLMapView but I prefer the way the navigationViewController is presented.

Is there anyway that I can add a bottom constraint to the navigationViewController to product a 300 space at the bottom of the screen?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to create a _custom transition animation_ with a custom UIPresentationController that sets the size and position of the view controller you're presenting (by overriding `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView`). Downloadable example here: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7

Comment: Of course the `frame` in my example is not the same as the `frame` you want, but that's unimportant for purposes of the example.

Comment: you can't set constraints to navigation controller. You need to create custom navigation controller to do so.

Comment: @matt is that not just pulling in another view?

Comment: @MahendraGP I get that you can't, due to the errors. But surly there is a work around or something else that can be done other than having to recreate the exact same view inside another view controller??